# Submitting form GET with multiple same name elements results in long querystring

Tags: jquery, forms, get

I have a `form[method=get]` which has a number of checkboxes all have the same **name**.

when the form is submitted, the url ends up looking like

```
?MyCB=0&MyCb=4&MyCB=10
```

I desire the GET request to appear in the browser as (which is valid and works).

```
?MyCB=0,4,10
```

Is there an attribute I can set on the form to do this?

A last resort would be to intercept the GET using jquery (which is why I have tagged as so incase there are any helper functions out there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just not even use $_GET and handle the entire form with jquery and then set the window.location to the array.

You can't add an attribute that allows forms to condense multiple $_GET variables into an array though unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery and do this:

```
<script>
function sendtheform(){

var theurldata = $("input.MyCBclass").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");

window.location ='yoururl.html?MyCB='+theurldata;
}
</script>
```

Here is the form elements HTML:

```
<input name="MyCB" class="MyCBclass" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="MyCB" class="MyCBclass" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input onClick="sendtheform()" type="button">
```

This will result in:

```
yoururl.html?MyCB=1,2
```